# pg_query() - "Cannot set connection to blocking mode (Error No. 8)

Tags: php, database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Our application is inserting data from CSV files to Redshift using a `COPY` query.  It uploads c. 700 GB in total across c. 11000 files.  Each file maps to one database table.  We run a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <table>` before and after each `COPY` for logging and sanity checking.

After a period of time (it seems to vary) the call to `pg_query()` returns this `E_NOTICE` PHP error:

```
pg_query() - "Cannot set connection to blocking mode (Error No. 8)
```

This is returned for the `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <table>` query; our application propagates all PHP Errors to Exceptions.  Removing this propagation gives us this error message in addition to the `E_NOTICE` above on both the `SELECT` and the `COPY`:

```
Failed to run query: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
```

The `COPY` query definitely does not actually insert the files.

Once present, this error happens on every attempt to insert a file.  It does not seem to resolve itself.

We initially had one database connection open (opened with `pg_connect()`) at the start of the script and re-used it for all following `SELECT`s and `COPY`s.  When we got the `E_NOTICE` above we then tried - just as an experiment - opening a fresh connection for each query.  This changed nothing.

our current pgsql settings in the PHP ini file are:

```
pgsql.allow_persistent = Off
pgsql.auto_reset_persistent = Off
pgsql.max_persistent = -1
pgsql.max_links = -1
pgsql.ignore_notice = 0
pgsql.log_notice = 0
```

What could be causing this error and how could it be resolved?

**Update** - See the attached screen.  It seems we only have the default query queue with 'concurrency' set to 5 and the timeout set to 0 MS?

[image]

Also: we only have these DB users connected while the application is running (the one with 'username_removed' is the only one that is created by our application):

```
main=# select * from stv_sessions;
       starttime        | process |                     user_name                      |                      db_name
------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
 2017-03-24 10:07:49.50 |   18263 | rdsdb                                              | dev
 2017-03-24 10:08:41.50 |   18692 | rdsdb                                              | dev
 2017-03-30 10:34:49.50 |   21197 | <username_removed>                              | main
 2017-03-24 10:09:39.50 |   18985 | rdsdb                                              | dev
 2017-03-30 10:36:40.50 |   21605 | root                                               | main
 2017-03-30 10:52:13.50 |   23516 | rdsdb                                              | dev
 2017-03-30 10:56:10.50 |   23886 | root                                               | main
```

Comment: For the file that failed to load, how long did the `copy` run? I think it must have run for more than 15 minutes, because your file sizes must be huge.

Comment: How many connections do you see in 'select * from stv_sessions'. What is the concurrency and Timeout set for that usergroup queue?

Comment: @RedshiftGuy - Five connections are in the stv_sessions table: three are made by the user 'rdsdb' and I think are always running as part of Redshift?  Then there's one I've made through the 'psql' client on the command line and finally just one that is made by my application. (I mentioned in my original post that I temporarily tried opening a new connection for each query; this is not the case any more).

Also - how can I check the concurrency/timeout for that usergroup queue?  Thanks.

Comment: @RedshiftGuy - Updated the question to include info on connected users and our query queue settings.

Comment: Use `SELECT reltuples::bigint AS estimate FROM pg_class where relname='mytable';` instead of  `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable;`

Comment: @Amir - Could you explain the benefit of this please?

Comment: @Pete171, Postgresql seems to have problem in counting big tables with `SELECT COUNT(*)`

Comment: @Pete171 - Wow! looks okay on redshift end. After running your copy command, can you check 'stl_connection_log' table during same time frame if the connection was authenticated?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change *pg_connect* to *pg_pconnect*? This will reuse an existent connection and will decrease the connections to your database and the server will run smoothly.

I would say to **never do a count using ***. You are forcing the database to create a hash for each register and count it. Use some value that is unique. If you don't have it, consider create a sequence and use it in an "auto_increment" field.
I see that you work with huge files and any performance improvement will help your work

You can also check your blocking mode config.

I got this searching the web, may work for you.
*"From changing pgsql.auto_reset_persistent = Off to On and restarting Apache, this resolves the error."*

My last advice is about transactions, if you are using transactions you can set your count Select to ignore locked rows and it will make your count run faster.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-ROWS

Answer (score 0):

Your connection may be timing out.  Make sure you enable keepalives in your connection options.

Setting `keepalives=1` in your connection string should send keepalive packets and prevent the connection from timing out.  You can also try setting `keepalives_idle=60`.

By default connections from your OS may not have the ability to request keepalives so these settings will appear to not work until you also update the corresponding OS level settings.

Take a look at the similar question [TCP Keep-Alive PDO Connection Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39962666/tcp-keep-alive-pdo-connection-parameter) for more information.